# (node:81285) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments required

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to use bcrypt to compare passwords. I'm getting the token and the userID back, but it's giving me this error. Any advice?

This is the register route. I'm verifying if a user already exists, and if not, a user can create an account with an encrypted password

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
        const {username, password} = req.body
        
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({username})
        
        if(user)return res.json({ message: "User already exists!"})
        const hashedPword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
        const newUser = new UserModel({username, password: hashedPword})
        await newUser.save()
        res.json({message: "user registered successfully!"})
    })
```

This is the login route, where Im verifying the username and comparing the passwords

```
    router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
        const {username, password} = req.body
    
        try {
            const user = await UserModel.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    
            if(!user) {
                return res.json({message: "user does not exist"})
            }
        
            const isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            if (!isPasswordValid) return res.status(400).send({message: "Invalid Username or Password"});
    
           
            const authData = {id: user._id}
            const token = jwt.sign(authData, "secret")
            res.json({token, userID: user._id})
            
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
     })
```